# Highcharts - Even tick with uneven spacing

Tags: highcharts

I am working on a requirement where i need two panes on Y axis with one common x axis. I am able to achieve this. However on each Y axis i need units from 10 to 100 where say 10 to 50 have spacing of say 1 cm and 50 to 100 have spacing of 5 cms.
This is depicted in attached screen print.

Is there a feature in highstock which i can use to achieve this? I researched tickPixelInterval along with lograthmic axis but could not go far :(

Also, i need to ensure the scale on y axis (10 to 100) always show up even if i do not have data points mapping to it. In other words if i have only two data points say 60 and 90 then the categories below 60 is not visible on the chart. Howevere i need all 10 to 100 mapping to be visible at all times.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. THANK YOU in advance!

Comment: screen print - http://forum.highcharts.com/topic33268/

Answer (score 1):

1. Axis scale from 10 to 100

Using min and max for axis it is possible to set scale. In case scale if not preserved (e.g. from 11 to 99) setting startOnTick and endOnTick to false for axis will resolve the issue.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kcrv97sm/

```
yAxis: {
    min: 10,
    max: 100,
    tickInterval: 10,
    showLastLabel: true,
    startOnTick: false,
    endOnTick: false
}
```

API: 
http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.min
http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.startOnTick

2. Uneven spacing

Default available axis types are "linear", "logarithmic", "datetime" or "category".

In your case this is not enough. You could try to write or apply custom Highstock extension - wrapper, then will change scale.

Example 1 - one function: http://jsfiddle.net/a3fLLyo4/73/

Example 2 - two functions: http://jsfiddle.net/a3fLLyo4/69/

You would have to come up with function(s) that will describe how all is set on axis. You didn't specified if in between of 60 and 80 scale should be linear or more complex.

```
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Axis.prototype, 'translate', function (proceed) {
    // Normal Translation
    var result = proceed.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));

    // Apply curving
    if (this.options.curvature) {
        var val = 1 - Math.sqrt(1 - Math.pow(((arguments[1]-this.min) / (this.max - this.min)), 2)),
            result = (this.len * val);
        if (arguments[2] == 0) {
            result = this.len - result;
        }
    }
    return result;

});
```

Comment: Perfect...Thank you..this helps my implementation to much greater extent... :)